# Creating a function to edit and delete inputs in a table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a code that works like this:

- I have a DB named 'phonebook'
- Where I store contacts in a table named 'contacts'
- This is my code for the two main pages I use:

FORM PAGE (phonebook.blade.php):

```
....... some css here and stuff .......

<body>

        <h1>Contact Form</h1><br/>

                    {{-- FORM --}}

        <form method = "POST" action = "contacts">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class = "form-group"> 
                <label for = "name">Name</label><br/>
                <input type = "text" id = "name" class = "form-control" name = "name" placeholder = "Name your Name" value = "{!! old('name') !!}">
            </div><br/>

            <div class = "form-group"> 
                <label for = "lastname">Lastname</label><br/>
                <input type = "text" id = "lastname" class = "form-control" name = "lastname" placeholder = "Name your Lastname" value = "{!! old('lastname') !!}">                        
            </div><br/>

            <div class = "form-group 
                @if($errors->has('email')) 
                    has-error
                @endif">
                <label for = "email">E-mail</label><br/>
                <input type = "text" id = "email" class = "form-control" name = "email" placeholder = "somesomething@email.com" >
                @if($errors->has('email')) 
                    <p class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> 
                @endif
            </div><br/>

            <div class = "form-group 
                @if($errors->has('phone'))
                    has-error
                @endif">
                <label for = "phone">Phone Number</label><br/>
                <input type = "text" id = "phone" class = "form-control" name = "phone" placeholder = "I'll call you">
                @if($errors->has('phone')) 
                    <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</p> 
                @endif
            </div><br/>

            <div class = "form-group"> 
                <label for = "address">Address</label><br/>
                <input type = "text" id = "address" class = "form-control" name = "address" placeholder = "I'll even visit you" value = "{!! old('address') !!}">                        
            </div><br/>

            <button type = "submit" class = "submit">Submit Information</button>
            <a href="contacts"><button type = "button">View Contacts</button></a>
        </form>      
    </body>
</html>
```

When I hit the "`Submit Information`" button, the contact is stored in the 'contacts' table and I get redirected to the page "`contacts.blade.php`".

When I hit the "`View contacts`" button, I get redirected to "`contacts.blade.php`" too.

This is the "`contacts.blade.php`"

```
....... some css and scripts here .......


<body>
        <h1>Contacts</h1>

        <br/>

        <a href = "phonebook"><button class = "ret" type = "button">Add New Entry</button></a>

        <br/><br/>

        <table class = "contacts">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID       </th>
                    <th> Name     </th>
                    <th> Lastname </th>
                    <th> E-Mail   </th>
                    <th> Phone    </th>
                    <th> Address  </th>
                    <th> Edit     </th>
                    <th> Delete   </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach($contact as $contact)                                                      
                    <tr class = "tableBody">
                        <td class = "id">       {{ $contact->id }}                                                      </td>
                        <td class = "name">     {{ $contact->name }}                                                    </td>
                        <td class = "lastname"> {{ $contact->lastname }}                                                </td>
                        <td class = "email">    {{ $contact->email }}                                                   </td>
                        <td class = "phone">    {{ $contact->phone }}                                                   </td>
                        <td class = "address">  {{ $contact->address }}                                                 </td>
                        <td class = "edit">     <button class = "btnedit" onclick = "editContact()">Edit</button>       </td>
                        <td class = "delete">   <button class = "btndelete" onclick = "deleteContact()">Delete</button> </td>
                    </tr>                       
                @endforeach
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br/>
        <a href = "phonebook"><button class = "ret" type = "button">Add New Entry</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please, notice I already have a button to edit and delete my contacts, and the name of the functions, `editContact()` and `deleteContact()`.

**What I need:**

When I hit "EDIT" I want to be redirected to a page that uses the same structure of the FORM PAGE, with the input fields filled with the info of that specific row where I hit the EDIT button.
Once I finish editing the entry, I hit the "Submit Information" button and the things I just edited **replaces** the old stuff, **instead** of creating a **new entry** in the table. **edit**: I prefer using Javascript to do this, so no problems about answers where JS appears.

Delete button:
When I hit the "Delete" button, I want the contact to be removed from my table and the next entries goes up one row, taking the place of the old stuff. **edit**: I also prefer using JS for this button.

Example:
I have a contact in the fourth row.
I delete this contact.
the fifth entry in the table goes up one position
so, it becomes the fourth entry in the table.
also, the sixth entry goes up one position, becoming the fifth entry.
and so on.

I already have the logic, but I lack the commands to make the functions work. 
Also, I'm fairly new to PHP and Laravel.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for datatables? https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: Not quite, Troyer. But I liked the repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute is going to try and use javascript so you don't really want to do that if you are trying to do this with PHP.

It should probably be a link (stylized like a button if you want it to look like a button) which points to whatever route you have setup to edit the contact.  That route would take the ID of the contact and then show a form where all the fields are pre-populated with that contact id's information.

The form would then point to another route which would take the ID and the contact information and update the record in the database with all entered information on the edit form.

Same goes for the delete button, it would just need to be a link which points to a route which is setup for deleting a contact, using the contact id.  Then it would probably redirect back to this same page or wherever you wanted it to go after that.

I'd check out Resource Controllers, it might make your life a lot easier because it basically sets up the controller for you with all the methods it needs for CRUD operations as well as the routes.  You just need to go through each method in the controller which gets generated and implement them how you see fit.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Actually I want to use Javascript here, because I'm more knowledgeable in that area. Thank you for the input, I will update the info in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a new page that will use your database to fill in the fields by passing through the ID.

- You need a simple `SELECT` command to get the row depending on the ID you are editing: `SELECT FROM table WHERE ID=yourid`. Then by submitting you will not use `INSERT INTO table VALUES` you will use `UPDATE table SET NAME=new_name WHERE ID=yourid`
- Accordingly on the delete page, pass through the ID and use `DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=yourid`

If you do not know how to pass the ID through pages it is done through `POST` and `GET`